# JDBC query does not see session.flush modifications on the same transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-orm

I have a project with Spring and Hibernate.

After an insert made with hibernate I cannot see the data in the jdbc sql even thou I've called the session.flush method. Any idea why this is happening?

My configuration is like this:

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>ro.asf.capone.common.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${agency.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${agency.hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${agency.hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">ehcache.xml</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</prop>
        </props>
    </property>     
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="auditInterceptor" />
</bean>
```

I've also tried `<prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>` with the same result.

The datasource is hiraki ds but I've tried bonecp with the same result.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
 //     dataSource.setAutoCommit(false);
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(jdbcDriver);
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(jdbcUsername);
    dataSource.setPassword(jdbcPassword);
    dataSource.setIdleTimeout(60000);
    dataSource.setMinimumIdle(0);
    dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(2);
    return dataSource;
}
```

The code that I am using is:

```
 final AuditUsers typ = new AuditUsers();
    typ.setEntityId(1l);
    typ.setLevel(29);
    final Serializable typid = getSession().save(typ);
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>> id: " + typid);
    getSession().flush();
    getSession().clear();
    final String sqltyp = "select * from AUDIT_USERS where id = " + typid;

  try(Connection con = getConnection(); Statement stm = con.createStatement()){
        System.out.println("!!!" + con.getAutoCommit());
        final ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sqltyp);
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println("RS filename: " + rs.getString("ENTITY_ID"));
        }
    }catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I do not get the rs's next value.

If I use the doWork method the result set has values but I do not want to use it like this.

```
                getSession().doWork(new Work() {

                @Override
                public void execute(final Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                    final Statement stm = connection.createStatement();
                    final ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sqltyp);
                    while(rs.next()){
                        System.out.println("RS filename: " + rs.getString("ENTITY_ID"));
                    }
                }
            });
```

I have a HibernateDAOSupport class for setting accessing datasource and sessionfactory that are set from spring configuration xml:

```
public abstract class HibernateDAOSupport {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private DataSource dataSource;


    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(final SessionFactory sessionFactory)    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
         return dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(final DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public void setDs(final DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
         return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

And the xml:

```
 <bean id="hibernateDAO" class="ro.asf.capone.server.dao.HibernateDAOSupport" abstract="true">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
```

Comment: `getConnection` will open a new connection, which is part of the current transaction and thus doesn't see the changes. Instead of using a plain connection use a `JdbcTemplate` which will use the thread bound connection.

Comment: I cannot find the JdbcTemplate in the hibernate4. That is the reason I created the HibernateDAOSupport class. But I will check the new connection remark. Thanks

Comment: I found the JdbcTemplate in the spring classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this by changing the `getConnection` implementation in `HibernateDAOSupport` class with this:

```
public Connection getConnection(){
    return org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
}
```

Thanks M. Deinum for pointing out that a new connection is offered from the datasource and not the same one gets used. I was under the impression that a single connection spans a transaction.